# mattplotlib animation in jupyter with large video files

Tags: python, matplotlib, jupyter-notebook, ipywidgets

I am trying to show a video in a jupyter notebook. Now, the jupyter server is running on a remote AWS EC2 machine, which is also hosting the data. I am using `ssh` and port forwarding to create the notebook from my local machine.

My issue is that I need to be able to play large video files (>100000 frames) and I was using the animation framework of `matplotlib` to do it. I tried `opencv` and raw `matplotlib` but I could never get it to work properly. I also tried the video widget and that also fails to load the large video file.

My issue is that I can never get it to display the whole video. Either it will just play a few seconds worth of video, or it will take forever to load. My suspicion is that it preloads the whole video, which would just crash everything. My usage is as follows:

```
%matplotlib inline
from IPython.display import clear_output, display
from IPython.display import HTML
import cv2
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from matplotlib import animation
from matplotlib import rc
import time
import numpy as np
```

Use `opencv` to load the video.

```
cap = cv2.VideoCapture('test.avi')
```

Now we try and load the video as animation

```
total = int(cap.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_COUNT))
print(total)  # 

ret, frame = cap.read() 
fig = plt.figure() 
ax = fig.add_subplot(111) 

im = ax.imshow(cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB), animated=True) 
plt.close()  # clear the initial image

def updatefig(*args): 
    ret, frame = cap.read() 
    im.set_array(cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)) 
    return im 

ani = animation.FuncAnimation(fig, updatefig, interval=33, repeat=False, cache_frame_data=False) 
HTML(ani.to_html5_video())
```

The thing is this only loads about 3 seconds worth of video. I can add `frames=total` as a parameter but then it never loads. I am guessing it is loading the whole video in one go, which will not work.

Comment: Have you tried the IPython native video widget as an alternative? https://ipython.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api/generated/IPython.display.html#IPython.display.Video

Comment: @ac24 The problem is with large video files, it just crashed. Maybe this also preloads everything.